# How to assign downloaded URL from Storage to AsyncImage?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-storage

My previous question was similar to this one, I got a superficial answer, it is correct without a doubt (in the comments to the question), but I still did not understand how exactly to remote an image from `Storage` in `AsyncImage` (`item.pic`)? -*see code below*.

In all the examples and tutorials, downloading the `URL` goes with `putData` when you upload the image, but in my case it won't work.

There is a class `getData` with all parameters for displaying data from firebase (*title, desc, pic*):

```
class getData : ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var datas = [dataType]()
    
    init() {
        
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        db.collection("items").getDocuments { (snap, err) in
            
            if err != nil {
                
                print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }
            
            for i in snap!.documents {
                
                let id = i.documentID
                let title = i.get("title") as! String
                let description = i.get("description") as! String
                let pic = i.get("pic") as! String
                
                self.datas.append(dataType(id: id, title: title, description: description, pic: pic))
            }
        }
    }
}


struct dataType : Identifiable {
     
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var title : String
    var description : String
    var pic : String
}
```

How can I output an image to `AsyncImage` from `getData`?
I understand that I need to download the `URL`, but any attempts come down to nothing.
It would be more accurate to ask how to correctly bind the `pic` parameter in `getData` to the `url` in `AsyncImage`?

```
struct RecentItemsView: View {
    
    var item: dataType
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 15) {
            AsyncImage(url: URL(string: item.pic), content: { image in // item.pic
                image.resizable()
                }, placeholder: {
                    ProgressView()
                    })
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12.5))
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8, content: {
                
                Text(item.title)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                Text(item.description)
                    .font(.caption)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                
            })
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
```

One of the examples I tried was to download the `URL` from `Storage` inside `getData` class.

```
                let storage = Storage.storage()
                let storageRef = storage.reference()
                let spaceRef = storageRef.child("itemImages/\(pic)")
                
                spaceRef.downloadURL { url, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Failed to download url:", error)
                        return
                    } else {
                        print(url!)
                        
                    }
                }


Failed to download url: Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13010 "Object itemImages/itemImages/FD80E18F-C2C0-4E9F-BE8A-7A6AADAC31A3.jpg does not exist." UserInfo={object=itemImages/itemImages/FD80E18F-C2C0-4E9F-BE8A-7A6AADAC31A3.jpg, ResponseBody={
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found."
  }
}, bucket=somee-letters-and-numbers.com, data={length = 65, bytes = 0x7b0a2020 22657272 6f72223a 207b0a20 ... 2e220a20 207d0a7d }, data_content_type=application/json; charset=UTF-8, NSLocalizedDescription=Object itemImages/itemImages/FD80E18F-C2C0-4E9F-BE8A-7A6AADAC31A3.jpg does not exist., ResponseErrorDomain=com.google.HTTPStatus, ResponseErrorCode=404}
```

Comment: You need to get the full url “https://…” from storage not the partial url you are saving.

Comment: Do you want to actually download the image data (what you're doing in your last code block) or do you want to get the URL to use in AsyncImage? If the latter, see the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#generate_a_download_url

Comment: Also, you may want to consider adhering to the general Swift standards of naming types starting with capital letters and functions, properties, variables starting with lowercase -- it'll make it easier for others to read your code.

Comment: @jnpdx edited question in last block. Okay, how to download the `URL` is understandable (maybe I still screwed up because there is an error domain, but apparently this is due to the fact that this is again not a full `URL`), but how to bind it to the `pic` parameter?

Comment: Once you've downloaded the record from Firestore, start the storage download. Your storage call will look more like `let starsRef = storageRef.child("itemImages/\(pic)")`

Comment: @jnpdx I do everything as you say, also adding to it different data from the Firebase documentation, but everything leads to the same error that I indicated in the last block, also my last code is there.

Comment: I don't understand why you're trying to both download the data *and* get the download URL. I thought you just wanted the download URL? Instead of `localizedDescription`, you should just print the `error` itself -- it'll be more informative.

Comment: @jnpdx edited last block. I'm doing everything right rn... Why not found(404)? Why doesn't it exist? Why is the path repeated twice?: `"Object itemImages/itemImages/FD80E18F-C2C0-4E9F-BE8A-7A6AADAC31A3.jpg` 
Where could I screw up in three lines?

Comment: If itemImages is already included in pic, remove it from the storageRef path.

Comment: @jnpdx yeah, I actually did it and I have full `URL` rn, but now I try to figure out how to fix an error `unsupported URL`